# How to return database data from NodeJS Express routes?

Tags: node.js

Working with NodeJS for the first time, trying to build a public endpoint that an accept an XML file, convert it to JSON, save it to MongoDB, then send a 200 HTTP status code, if everything went well. But the Express route completes and sends a response long before the code writing to the database completes.

A slightly simplified version:

```
app.post('/ams', function (req, res) {

try {


    if (Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
    console.log("request body was empty");
    //      throw new EmptyBodyException(req.body);
            message = message + "Request body was empty \n";
    }

    let body_keys = Object.keys(req.body);
    let body_values = Object.values(req.body);
    let xml_string = body_keys[0] + ":"  + body_values[0];
        let xml = xml_string.trim();

        console.log("The trimmed XML:");
        console.log(xml);

    // convert XML to JSON
    xml2js.parseString(xml, (err, json) => {
    if(err) {
                message = "xml2js.parseString failed, xml was:." + xml + "\n\n" + err;
                console.log(message);
        res.status(500);
        res.send(message);
    }

    const documentType = json.Document.DocumentType;

    if (documentType == 945) {
        const shipment = json.Document.Shipment[0];
        const shipment_header = shipment.ShipmentHeader[0];
        const addresses = shipment.Addresses[0].Address;
        const order_header = shipment.Orders[0].Order[0].OrderHeader[0];
        const cartons = shipment.Orders[0].Order[0].Cartons[0].Carton;

        const unique_id = shipment_header.ShipmentID[0];

        found_document_promise = document_is_redundant(AMS_945, unique_id);
        found_document_promise.then(function (found_document) {

        if (found_document != null) {
                console.log("Redundant document. Perhaps a Pair Eyewear engineer was running a test?");
                res.status(200);
                        message = "Redundant document. Perhaps a Pair Eyewear engineer was running a test? documentType: " + documentType;
                res.send(message);
        } else {

            new AMS_945({
            shipment_header : shipment_header,
            addresses : addresses,
            order_header : order_header,
            cartons : cartons,
            unique_id : unique_id
            })
            .save()
            .then(function () {
                //  console.log("saved AMS_945");
                                message = "saved AMS_945";
                        res.status(200);
                        res.send(message);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                                message = "error when saving AMS_945 to database: " + "\n\n" + err;
                                console.log(message);
                        res.status(500);
                        res.send(message);
            });
        }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
                        message = "error when checking for a redundant AMS_945 document: " + "\n\n" + err;
                        console.log(message);
                res.status(500);
                res.send(message);
        });

 // down at the bottom I have some generic catch-all: 
  res.status(200);
  res.send("Catch all response.")_;
```

If I don't have the catch all response at the end then the connection simply hangs until the 30 second timeout is hit, and then I get 504 Bad Gateway.

With the catch-all response at the bottom, thankfully I don't get the timeout error, but I do get an error "Sending headers after response was sent" because at some point the database code returns and tries to send its response, but this is long after the Express route function has completed and sent that generic catch-all code that I have at the bottom.

I'd be happy to get rid of the catch-all res.send() and just have the res.send() inside the database code, but that never seems to return.

So how to I get the Express route function to wait till the database code has returned?

Comment: Do you see anything in the console? If you uncomment "saved AMS_945", does it get printed?

Comment: Yes, the data saves to the database without a problem. But how can I send a message to the external app that POSTed the data to our endpoint? It seems the Express route for POST has returned long before the database code is done working.

Comment: I suspect now the problem might be in how `res` is used. Try changing all to "chained" calls, e.g.: `res.status(200).send(message);` and don't use that catch-all.

Comment: Your try catch is not correctly setup, put all your code in try section and then catch the errors like this:
`try { // your code } catch(e) { // res.send()  }`